# split material ui style to other file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wish to remove all the styles from my main component.
All the JS style of the material UI is on the same file and it is starting to get long code.

I wish to create a new file that contains all the styles on other file and on Navbar.js I will just call the components, just same as CSS file that I call to class

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { Notifications, Pets } from "@mui/icons-material";
import {
  AppBar,
  Avatar,
  Badge,
  Box,
  InputBase,
  Menu,
  MenuItem,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

import React, { useState } from "react";

const StyledToolbar = styled(Toolbar)({
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
});

const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "white",
  padding: "0 10px",
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  width: "40%",
}));

const Icons = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "none",
  gap: "20px",
  alignItems: "center",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    display: "flex",
  },
}));

const UserBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  gap: "10px",
  alignItems: "center",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    display: "none",
  },
}));

const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <AppBar position="sticky">
      <StyledToolbar>
        <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" } }}>
          PALSAM
        </Typography>
        <Pets sx={{ display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" } }} />
        <Search>
          <InputBase placeholder="search..." />
        </Search>
        <Icons>
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="error">
            <MailIcon />
          </Badge>
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="error">
            <Notifications />
          </Badge>
          <Avatar
            sx={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/846741/pexels-photo-846741.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"
            onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)}
          />
        </Icons>
        <UserBox onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)}>
          <Avatar
            sx={{ width: 30, height: 30 }}
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/846741/pexels-photo-846741.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2"
          />
          <Typography variant="span">Jhon</Typography>
        </UserBox>
      </StyledToolbar>

      <Menu
        id="demo-positioned-menu"
        aria-labelledby="demo-positioned-button"
        open={open}
        onClose={(e) => setOpen(false)}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: "top",
          horizontal: "right",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new js file and add export before each const then you can import them from that file

```
export const StyledToolbar = styled(Toolbar)({
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between",
});
```

Comment: but is doesn't recognize Toolbar, so i need to import also Toolbar?

Comment: You can import toolbar inside new js file as well import { Toolbar } from "@mui/material"; otherwise it will not recognise